# Object form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a object form of a  file input in the form, How i can do it 
. How I can Create form object of file input

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="helooo">
  <input type="text" name="foo1" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="foo2" value="" id="r1"/>
<input type="file" name="f1" value="" id="r2"/>
<button type="submit" id="s1"> ab</button>
</form>




<script>
$(".quote_save").click(function() {
var oElements = {};
$('form'){
    oElements[this.name] =  = this.value;
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have the method and enctype(necessary for file input).

**HTML:**

```
<form id="helooo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="foo1" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="foo2" value="" id="r1"/>
<input type="file" name="f1" value="" id="r2"/>
<button type="submit" id="s1" class='quote_save'> ab</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
 $(function(){
 $(".quote_save").submit(function() {
  var form_data=$('#helooo').serialize();//string format
  var form_data=$('#helooo').serializeArray();//Arrayformat
});
});
</script>
```

Reference:-/ [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: whey you copy my answer ?

Comment: There is much difference between your answer and my answer

Comment: yes just you edit ...

Comment: everyone knows about serialize but you should give the answer the way it works.

Comment: Lol what you think i dont know ? if you not copy my answer then how your variable and my variable same .

Comment: try yourself .. if its possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<script>
 $(".quote_save").click(function() {

  var formData=$('#helooo').serialize();
});
</script>
```